# what index should I use?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting pretty slow performance for a pretty simple statement (3-4 seconds):

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table WHERE fname LIKE '%D%' OR fname LIKE '%S%' ORDER BY DATE(bday) DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

I have index on fname, another on bday and even a joint index on fname & bday. Here's my explain:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra

1   SIMPLE       table  ALL   NULL           NULL NULL     NULL 95856 Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: No index will help here. I would look for a full text search solution. MySQL has something build in: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @Wiseguy: Why did you delete your answer? It's a valid one (and probably the easiest help the query can get).

Comment: The `order by` is secondary, but yeah, still a problem. On a small enough set it wouldn't be terrible but really it should just be stored as a date type in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated no index will help. Personally I'd consider full text search overkill for this and add an other column to the table, fill it in on insert update and index that.

Like is for one offs.

Answer (score 4):

No index will help you here.

When you're using `LIKE '%something%` it's going to have to look at every row and do the string matching.

Comment: is there an alternative I can use? fulltext?

Comment: You *could*, yes ... but it may not do what you want given the way it works. What is it you're really trying to accomplish here is the question you need to ask yourself - more than likely you can add an additional (indexable) column to your table to represent what you're trying to search for.